# MS SQL ORDER BY ASC then DESC for addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting

I would like to order results up the street then back down the other side for field review workflow (100, 102, 104, 105, 103, 101).

I have :

```
ORDER BY 
    s.situs_street, 
    CAST([situs_num]%2 as integer), 
    CAST(situs_num as integer)
```

This gets me all the evens then the odds but they are both ascending.

Using :

```
ORDER BY
    s.situs_street, 
    CAST([situs_num]%2 as integer) ASC, 
    CAST(situs_num as integer) DESC
```

puts both even/odd descending. Have failed using `CASE` statement as well since I'm reverse sorting the same field.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of sorting? i am still not able to understand

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Evens before Odds and then Evens are Ascending, Odds are Descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY s.situs_street
          ,CASE WHEN [situs_num]%2 = 0 THEN situs_num ELSE 9999999 END ASC
          ,CASE WHEN [situs_num]%2 <> 0 THEN situs_num ELSE -1 END DESC
```

If you can take the remainder of situs_num without first casting then it is already numeric.  If not you would have to cast differently as follows

```
ORDER BY s.situs_street
          ,CASE WHEN CAST([situs_num] AS INT)%2 = 0 THEN  CAST([situs_num] AS INT) ELSE 9999999 END ASC
          ,CASE WHEN CAST([situs_num] AS INT)%2 <> 0 THEN  CAST([situs_num] AS INT) ELSE -1 END DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a tremendous help. -paul

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression to sort the column by putting even numbers first and then odd numbers. Among the groups classified, use one more sort on situs_num to get the desired result.

```
order by 
 s.situs_street
,case when cast([situs_num] as int)%2 = 0 then 1 else 2 end
,case when cast([situs_num] as int)%2 = 0 then cast([situs_num] as int) 
 else -cast([situs_num] as int) end
```

[**`Sample demo`**](http://rextester.com/edit/HGT77935)

or more simply (as suggested by Matt)

```
order by 
 s.situs_street
,cast([situs_num] as int)%2 --ordered by return value 0's first(even) and 1's next (odd)
,case when cast([situs_num] as int)%2 = 0 then cast([situs_num] as int) 
 else -cast([situs_num] as int) end
```

Comment: He wants to walk up Even and Down Odd

Comment: @Matt..i overlooked that. i changed the query now. thanks

Comment: I think I like yours better than mine, but just a note to simplify you don't actually need the case for your remainder because Evens 104%2 will always be 0 and Odd 101%2, 105%2 will always be 1